# Plot overlapping numeric columns with geom_bar

Tags: r, charts

I have a datatable dt in R which looks like :

```
Time    a    b
00:00   23   -2
00:10   36   -12
00:20   21   -4
00:30   76   5
```

I want to graph both columns a and b in a bar graph using geom_bar. Here's my code :

```
graph <- ggplot(data = dt) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Time, y=a), group = 1, stat = "identity", fill="blue", position="stack")+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Time, y=b), group = 1, stat = "identity", fill="red", position="stack")
```

Here is the result : [image]

Right now, when the blue bar has positive values, it is not shown because it overlaps with the red. I want the positive blue bars to also show on the graph, either over the red bars or as another color if need be. Can anyone help ?

Comment: The bars will be plotted in the order you specify them in the `ggplot` call.  So try switching the order (b then a) if you want the blue bars to be drawn over the red bars.

Comment: ...or make the color transparent if the red bars can have negative values too.